# Trying to get property with non-object in yii

Tags: php, yii

Im trying to get value from my database. But all the time yii tells me

> Trying to get property of non-object

I'm sure I have this property in my controller, sending to in my view and then I want to show it. But I cant.
Below is my controller function, it's a part of my controller.

```
$car_reservation = CarReservation :: find() -> all();
$projects=Project::find()
    //->select(SAAS.'project.*')
    // ->joinWith('projectMembers')
    //->where(SAAS.'project_member.user_id='.Yii::$app->user->id.' ')          
    ->orderBy('project_title ASC')
    ->all();  
    $users = User::find()->all();

    return $this->render($render, array('users'=>$users,'car_reservation'=>$car_reservation,'projects'=>$projects,'cars'=>$cars,'rooms'=>$rooms,'today' => $today, 'minute_list' => $minute_list, 'hours_list' => $hours_list, 'status' => $status, 'tasks' => $tasks, 'taskstatuses' => $taskstatus));
}
```

Then I want to show it in view.

```
<form action="javascript:void(0)" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="cars-edit-modal">
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active">
            <div class="row" >
                <div class="col-sm-6" >
                    <?= Yii::t('app','Select car') ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 mt10 p0i" >
                    <select class="form-control" name="car_id" data-rel="chosen-car" id="modal-car" data-placeholder="-
                        <?= Yii::t('app','select') ?>-"  >
                        <option  value="
                            <?= $car->car_name ?>" >-
                            <?= Yii::t('app','select') ?>-
                        </option>
                        <?php 
foreach($cars as $cr) { ?>
                        <option value='
                            <?= $cr->car_name ?>;'>
                            <?= $cr->car_name ?>
                        </option>
                        <?php }  ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 mt10 p0i" >
                    <textarea class="modal-input-button form-control" value="
                        <?= $car_reservation->car_reservation_note ?>" name="text_car_edit" id="modal-cars" data-placeholder="-
                        <?= Yii::t('app','Put a note') ?>-" >
                    </textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer pull-left w100p">
    <div class="col-sm-1 mt10 text-right" >
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="
            <?=Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken()?>" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                <?= Yii::t('app','Save') ?>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

I'm confused, because the yii doesn't know property of $car_reservation.

Comment: can you please edit your question with full error with line number and all

Answer (score 0):

try  with

```
$car_reservation = CarReservation::find()->all();

and var_dump( $car_reservation) 

and check is you get the models and the name you used in view match
```

You get the result for cars reservation with

```
$car_reservation = CarReservation :: find() -> all();
```

all() obtain a collection but you in your view refer to thes collection like if these are one ..

try

```
 $car_reservation = CarReservation :: find() ->one();
```

or if you need manage a collection do it properly with a foreach

Comment: im confused because in var dump is all the data, but in view not -.-

Comment: and i have set $car_reservation prompt in my controller and send into the view ...but in view doesn´t show it ..if i type var dump car reservation in view, the data are in it .. -.- ..

Comment: Well i solve problem with no property. Instead of find all i write find() ->one(); it works but now.. There is another problem: <pre>PHP Warning &#039;yii\base\ErrorException&#039; with message &#039;Creating default object from empty value&#039;

Comment: what do you mean i solve the problem with no property .., show the code you are using now in controller

Answer (score 0):

Trying to get non property object error is basically fired on one of three ways as folowing :

```
1) If you get empty result and u print that empty result.
2) If your result in array and you put object for getting particular property from result.
3) If your result in object and you put array sign for getting particular property.
I prefer you to please print the $car_reservation in controller first.
```

Answer (score -1):

here you have used  `<?= $car->car_name ?>" >` insted of  `<?= $cars->car_name ?>" >`. as i can see that when you rending in view part you pass `cars` instead of `car` so please change it and run the code.